# Using numpy where to find the minimum of an array

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause, astropy

I have two astropy tables, of different lengths::

```
print(type(a),  len(a))
print(type(b),  len(b))
<class 'astropy.table.table.Table'> 457
<class 'astropy.table.table.Table'> 355
```

I'm looking for the differences between the two tables, of which (obviously) will only be valid for the smaller number of the arrays::

```
delta = b - a 
print(type(delta),  len(delta))
```

I then what to find the values of 'a' and 'b' where the minimum is reached::

```
 a[np.where(delta = delta.min())]
 b[np.where(delta = delta.min())]
```

The latter works fine it seems, but for the former I get:

```
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 457 but corresponding boolean dimension is 355
```

Thoughts??

Comment: @roganjosh: the smallest `delta` is not per se the smallest value for `a` and/or `b`. The smallest delta is typically where `a` is the largest relatively to `b`.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the equality test, not the single '='?`delta == delta.min()`

Comment: With floats, the '==' test is problematic.  You may get one exact match, but unlikely to find 'all' values that match.  Isn't there a `argmin` that works for you `astropy` arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create the list of deltas with:

```
n = min(len(a), len(b))
delta = b[:n] - a[:n]
```

then we can calculate the index where `delta` is minimum with:

```
idx = np.argmin(delta)
```

and then we can obtain the corresponding values with:

```
am, bm = a[idx], b[idx]
```

Note that if there are places where `a` is larger than `b`, then the delta will be negative, and this can count as the smallest value. If you want the "absolute value" of the difference, you should add `np.abs(..)`:

```
delta = np.abs(b[:n] - a[:n])
```

Comment: Not sure this works...Here are my 'a' values:: 0.34011348
0.66411726
1.4680833
2.10739 here are are my 'b' values: 0.3401675752230224
0.6640512593824166
1.4678952200097393
2.1073723426193647 for some reason idx is 2... ??!!

Comment: @npross: and the values for `b`?

Comment: @npross: well there `b - a` is the smallest value, but if you want the smallest *difference* (absolute) value, then you should use the `delta` as described at the bottom.

Comment: And of course, the deltas are:: 5.409522302235459e-05
 -6.600061758343934e-05
-0.00018807999026071442
 -1.765738063541633e-05

Comment: @npross: if you use `delta = np.abs(b[:n] - a[:n])`, you get as index `3`.

Comment: I'm scrapping this question, it wasn't asked properly.

Comment: Argh, no, don't think this works... (!!!) If you want to see the full-blown code and example that I'm coding up, look at: https://github.com/d80b2t/VHzQ/blob/master/data/matching_LISTto_unWISE.ipynb

Comment: @npross: but I think the problem statement is a bit vague. It might be good if you rewrite the question with some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you get this error with the `where` code?  That error is produced by boolean making, the '==' test without the 'where'.

```
In [375]: a = np.random.rand(100)
In [376]: b = np.random.rand(50)
In [377]: delta = a[:50]-b

In [380]: dm = delta.min()
In [381]: dm
Out[381]: -0.8017596490704487
```

boolean masking of the longer `a` with `delta` produces this error:

```
In [384]: a[delta == dm]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-384-d8a934874c2c> in <module>()
----> 1 a[delta == dm]

IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 100 but corresponding boolean dimension is 50

In [386]: b[delta == dm]
Out[386]: array([0.91912184])
```

We can find the index of `dm` with `where` or with `argmin`.  We don't get that error with the `where`:

```
In [390]: np.argmin(delta)
Out[390]: 48
In [391]: np.where(delta == dm)
Out[391]: (array([48]),)
In [392]: a[np.where(delta == dm)]
Out[392]: array([0.11736219])
```